# How to render Jade in Electron?

Tags: javascript, express, pug, electron

In `Express` it is possible to set the `view engine` as `Jade` with the following code:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

So, this allows `Express` to read and return compiled `HTML` from `Jade` files directly.

How can I do this in `Electron`?

Answer (score 1):

I just built a [small module](https://github.com/yan-foto/electron-jade) that would intercept all `jade` protocols and compile everything ending with `.jade` and the rest would be considered as local files. You would use this in your main file as the following:

```js
'use strict';

var app = require('app');
var locals = {/* ...*/};
var j = require('electron-jade')({pretty: true}, locals);
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');

// Standard stuff

app.on('ready', function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });

  mainWindow.loadUrl('jade://' + __dirname + '/index.jade');
  // the rest...
});
```

Note that instead of `file://` you write `jade://`.

**DISCLAIMER**: this module is in its very early stages and the logic is still not mature enough.

---

**UPDATE**:

I published the package on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-jade

Comment: I think this can be a solution for me, I will try this when I get home. I analyzed your 'electron-jade' code, my question is, 'protocol' package is default in NodeJs or Electron?

Comment: The `protocol` is from electron itself. The only external package ist jade :)

Comment: A welcome contribution! Thank you. Is 'use strict' necessary?

Comment: Shouldn't it be require('electron-jade')(); instead require('./util/jade-protocol.js')({}); ?

Comment: How are jade locals set for each jade template?

Comment: @seongjoo `use strict` is not required but I would recommend it :) and the example had a typo that I fixed. Thanks for noting.